# Why do names of Rails gems & plugins sometimes contain author name?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, plugins, github, rubygems

When it comes to adding gems/plugins I notice that sometimes the author name is prepended to the gem/plugin name, whereas other times it isn't. Is there any reasoning behind this?

Example:

```
config.gem "thoughtbot-factory_girl", :source => "http://gems.github.com"
```

Why not have it as:

```
config.gem "factory_girl", :source => "http://gems.github.com"
```

When do you differentiate between the two?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When [GitHub](http://github.com) used to auto-build and host gems, they enforced a namespacing scheme by username.  This is why github gems are prefixed with a username.  GitHub embraces forking projects; hence the need for the prefixed usernames.  GitHub was never really a good place for the canonical gem names, so they [decided to drop their automatic gem hosting](http://github.com/blog/515-gem-building-is-defunct)* when [Gemcutter](http://gemcutter.org/) launched.  Since then, even the original host of canonical gems, [RubyForge](http://rubyforge.org/), stopped hosting gems in favor of Gemcutter.  Gemcutter is now the canonical source for all gems.

To make this easy for everyone, http://gems.rubyforge.org now points to http://gemcutter.org.

*GitHub announced that they would continue to host all old username namespaced gems for at least one more year.

---

With regards to [factory_girl](http://gemcutter.org/gems/factory_girl), that too is now hosted on Gemcutter.  Your config only needs to look like this now:

```
config.gem "factory_girl"
```

...but I suggest also adding a version number for your projects (you'll thank me when you come back to a stale project later):

```
config.gem "factory_girl", :version => "1.2.3"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Ryan. You explained it well.

Answer (score 1):

Because there are several projects with similar funcitonality, but provided by different authors.  Maybe some of them are forks of the other ones.  Or maybe they just have a common interface for a specific task.

Quick googleing yields the following authors:

- [javan's factory_girl](http://github.com/javan/factory_girl)
- [thoughtbot's factory_girl](http://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl)
- [mattmatt's factory_girl](http://github.com/mattmatt/factory_girl)

To distinguish them, it's useful to prepend author's nickname to gem name.